# Optimizing this C# algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm

This is a algorithm question, I have solution but it has performance issue.

> **Question Description**
>
> There are n variables and m requirements. Requirements are represented as (x <= y), which means the x-th variable must be smaller or equal to the y-th variable. Assign nonnegative numbers smaller than 10 to each variable. Please calculate how many different assignments that match all requirements. Two assignments are different if and only if at least one variable is assigned different number in these two assignment. Module the answer by 1007.
>
> **Input Format:**
>
> First line of the input contains two integers n and m.
> Then following m lines each containing 2 space-seperated integers x and y, which means a requirement (x <= y).
>
> **Output Format:**
>
> Output the answer in one line.
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> 0 < n < 14
>
> 0 < m < 200
>
> 0 <= x, y < n
>
> **Sample Input:**
>
> 6 7
>
> 1 3
>
> 0 1
>
> 2 4
>
> 0 4
>
> 2 5
>
> 3 4
>
> 0 2
>
> **Sample Output**:
>
> 1000

Below is my solution. it takes too long time get result when n=13 and m=199 but the acceptable time is 5 seconds.

So can anyone think of a better way to optimize this further? Thank you.

My current solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication81
{
    class Program
    {
        const int N = 10;
        static List<Condition> condition = new List<Condition>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] line1 = Console.ReadLine().Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int n = int.Parse(line1[0]);
            int m = int.Parse(line1[1]);

            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                string[] line = Console.ReadLine().Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                condition.Add(new Condition()
                {
                    X = int.Parse(line[0]),
                    Y = int.Parse(line[1])
                });
            }

            //
            List<int[]> rlist = new List<int[]>();

            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                int[] assignments = new int[n];
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    assignments[i] = -1;
                assignments[0] = j;
                rlist.Add(assignments);
            }
            for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                List<int[]> rlist2 = new List<int[]>(rlist.Count*5);
                for (int k = 0; k < rlist.Count; k++)
                {
                    for (int l = 0; l < N; l++)
                    {
                        rlist[k][j] = l;
                        if (CanPassCondition(rlist[k]))
                            rlist2.Add((int[])rlist[k].Clone());
                    }
                }
                rlist = rlist2;
            }

            Console.Write(rlist.Count % 1007);
        }


        private static bool CanPassCondition(int[] p)
        {
            foreach (var c in condition)
            {
                if (p[c.X] == -1 || p[c.Y] == -1)
                    continue;

                if (p[c.X] > p[c.Y])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    class Condition
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("x:{0}, y:{1}", X, Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps put some logging to see if there is any unnessessary execution. Adding timing blocks to see where something is taking a long time to execute.

Comment: looks more like a c++ code rather than c# code

Comment: In **any case** even if a for-loop only is a single liner, place those damn curly brackets.

Comment: @SatelliteSD The code will execute and compile correctly regardless of whether the brackets are used. It's a matter of style. Both are acceptable.

Comment: @sasikt for a C++ code, there are quite few (literally none) manual deallocations.

Comment: @zespri It is good to advocate curly braces everywhere, if only for consistency.

Comment: @sasikt definitely not C++. I don't remember C++ having `for..in`.

Comment: @JanDvorak not necessarily. I'm in the pro-curly-braces camp. But there are people that feel that code looks more concise, with less clutter, when the braces are omitted for single-liners. The designers of the language would not give this option if it were totally useless. It is ok, to express one's opinion and believes, but caution has to be exercised when an advice is given to students on the matters that are not unambiguous. At the very least merits of the both approaches have to be made known. Also it's better to avoid being rude (re: "damn curly brackets").

Comment: Can you explain your solution?

Comment: @JanDvorak What i mean is power of c# is missing especially in loops. Something like this can be used to create a list instead of iterating using for loops. List<int> x = Enumerable.Repeat(value, count).ToList();

Comment: @zespri I do skip curly braces myself sometimes as well. If I do that on production, however, I almost always add them later anyways (most often because I need them)

Comment: @IsaacCambron this is a question from hackerrank.com. the page is here https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/requirement

Comment: To end this curly brackets chat I've started, read the corresponding Joel article (http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html).

Comment: +1 @rockXrock for pointing the source out.. It needs to mentioned somewhere that this is part of a challenge ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution in Java that works quite fast for me even with n=13, m=199:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Assignments
{
    private static Map <String, Long> solutions = new HashMap <String, Long> ();

    private static boolean [][] constraints;

    private static long solve (int n, int [] low, int [] high)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            sb.append (low [i]);
            sb.append (high [i]);
        }

        String signature = sb.toString ();

        Long result = solutions.get (signature);
        if (result == null)
        {
            result = Long.valueOf (doSolve (n, low, high));
            solutions.put (signature, result);
        }

        return result.longValue ();
    }

    private static long doSolve (int n, int [] low, int [] high)
    {
        if (n == 0) return 1;
        else
        {
            long result = 0;

            for (int i = low [n - 1]; i <= high [n - 1]; i++)
            {
                int [] l = new int [n - 1];
                int [] h = new int [n - 1];

                for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
                {
                    l [j] = constraints [n - 1][j] ? Math.max (low [j], i) : low [j];
                    h [j] = constraints [j][n - 1] ? Math.min (high [j], i) : high [j];
                }

                result += solve (n - 1, l, h);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader reader = 
            new BufferedReader (
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String nm = reader.readLine ();
        String [] pair = nm.split(" ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(pair [0]);
        int m = Integer.parseInt(pair [1]);

        constraints = new boolean [n][];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            constraints [i] = new boolean [n];

        int [] low = new int [n];
        int [] high = new int [n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            high [i] = 9;

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            String ab = reader.readLine();
            pair = ab.split (" ");
            int a = Integer.parseInt(pair [0]);
            int b = Integer.parseInt(pair [1]);
            constraints [a][b] = true;
        }

        System.out.println(solve (n, low, high));
    }
}
```

Actually, once you have 13 variables, you may have only 156 (13 * 12) meaningful constraints, but though.

Sample input:

```
13 1
3 8
```

Output:

```
5500000000000
```

Another sample input:

```
13 12
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9
9 10
10 11
11 12
```

Output:

```
497420
```

Comment: Hardest test is: 13 1 not 13 199. Counting of all permutations is incorrect solution for this task, as result may have value n!

Comment: My algorithm almost instantly returns `5500000000000` for n = 13, m = 1.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov thank you for your answer. there are 2 good points I learnt from it. 1) store constraints in a bool array; 2) store partial answer and reuse them to avoid computing them 2nd time. PS. last line of code is hardcoded 13 which should be n and the correct answer should be moduled by 1007.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov would be great if you add some explanation about your algorithm also

Comment: Given your code and this input: http://pastebin.com/raw/jNnDN83E the right answer is 1000 but your code outputs 25168 ;P